# MATLAB built-in menu function

Tags: matlab

Can any one give me hints on how I can use a Matlab built-in menu function to calculate areas  for example of cylinder,cycle and rectangle without printing the menu choices in the script? Thank you.

For example the script below calculates area but prints out the menu choices

```
%areaMenu
%this script asks the user for a type of area 
%and prints the area using if-else
%units are assumed to be inches
%display a menu
disp('Menu');
disp('1. Cylinder');
disp('2. Circle');
disp('3. Rectangle');
%choice selection
i=input('Please select your choice now: ');
if i==1
    disp('well! your choice is cylinder');
r=input('enter radius: ');
%error check
if (r<=0)
    disp('Error! Please enter a positive number')
    r=input('enter radius again: ');
end
l=input('enter length: ');
%error check
if l<=0
    disp('Error! Please enter a positive number')
    l=input('enter length again: ');
end
%area calculated and print
%assume the cylinder is closed both sides
area=2*pi*r*r+2*pi*r*l;
fprintf('The area is %.2f\n',area);
elseif i==2
    disp('well! your choice is cycle')
r=input('enter radius: ');
%error check
 if (r<=0)
    disp('Error! Please enter a positive number')
    r=input('enter radius again: ');
end
%area calculated and print
area=pi*r*r;
fprintf('The area is %.2f\n',area);
elseif i==3
    disp('well! your choice is rectangle')
l=input('enter length: ');
%error check
if l<=0
    disp('Error! Please enter a positive number')
    l=input('enter length again: ');
end
w=input('enter width: ');
%error check
if w<=0
    disp('Error! Please enter a positive number')
    w=input('enter width again: ');
end
%area calculated and print
area=l*w;
fprintf('The area is %.2f\n',area);
else
fprintf('invalid choice! Enter a valid choice next time');
end
end
```

Comment: Please be more specific on your problem. What do you consider to be a menu-function?

Comment: Did you try looking at the documentation for [`menu`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/menu.html)?

Comment: @pyStarter:I have try editing the post now

Comment: @Notlikethat:Yes I tried but In this case I want to know how to use built-in menu function without printing the menu choices

Comment: The function is ok. I dont understand what do you want to not print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the built-in function is as simple as replacing this:

```
disp('Menu');
disp('1. Cylinder');
disp('2. Circle');
disp('3. Rectangle');
%choice selection
i=input('Please select your choice now: ');
```

with this:

```
i = menu('Choose shape', 'Cylinder', 'Circle', 'Rectangle');
```

Alternatively, using a cell array:

```
shapes = {'Cylinder', 'Circle', 'Rectangle'};
i = menu('Choose shape', shapes);
```

Also, `menu` ensures that a valid number was chosen, so you'd no longer need that check in your code.